# How to change a text file into a list?

Tags: python, list, file

I already know how to get a text file into python but...I now want to turn that file into a `list`.

My file:

```
1
2
3
```

My code:

```
file = open("File.txt", "r")
file = list(file)
```

Is there a way to actually make it into something that works? And if you find an answer please make it simple.

Comment: What do you mean "something that works". The code you posted *works*, so what is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** 
My final solution.
Thanks to @juanpa.arrivillaga for the hint that the intermediate iterator-operation is not necessary

```
map(str.strip, open('asd.txt'))
```

Or if you like it more, then this:

```
[x.strip() for x in open('File.txt')]
```

Comment: Why `tuple()` and not `list()`?

Comment: Because I thought `touple(open(xx))` would be a "hidden" gem; didnt know that `list(open(xx))` does work exactly the same.

Comment: What do you mean a "hidden" gem?

Comment: Both open the generator and build an iterable. I was just curious

Comment: Why use `list` or `tuple` at all? You can `map` or use a list comprehension directly on the file-handler without creating an unecessary intermediate data structure.

Comment: Thanks for that hint; I edited my answer; seems the most simple, short, and concise version to me now

Comment: Personally, I like `rstrip('\n')` as the leading/trailing spaces might need preserved

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo -e "one\ntwo\nthree" > /tmp/list.txt
$ cat /tmp/list.txt 
one
two
three
$ python -c "fh = open('/tmp/list.txt'); print(fh.readlines())"
['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']
```

Comment: Not sure the shell is necessary just to answer `readlines()`...

Comment: true, it seemed simplest for creating the txt file used in the example as well, but you are right, it adds an unnecessary abstraction SollyBunny may not be familiar with

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open('filename.txt').readlines()
f = [int(i.strip('\n')) for i in f]

print(f)
```

Answer (score -2):

you could use numpy's loadtxt if your entries are numbers

```
import numpy as np
data = np.loadtxt('test.txt')
```